# k-means clustering by blocks for large images

Tags: python-3.x, k-means

I'm trying to find a way to run a k-means clustering over a large image size (16GB) without loading the whole array into python. I already have a code that is able to read the image by blocks to make other kind of raster calculations, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make the k-means.

I've been looking at `sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans` but it requires the complete array to be loaded, collapsing the memory. Another option I was testing was making a copy of the array by blocks in the hard drive using `numpy.memmap`, but it takes a lot of time to make the local copy, making the code inefficient. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Check this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226494413_Parallel_kh-Means_Clustering_for_Large_Data_Sets) out. It shows a possible way to parallelize k-means, using the h-means algo. For implementation, you can chunk read your data and throw each chunk to a thread. The centroids have to be shared among the threads. Re-assigning membership can be done on each thread, but re-computing new centroids have to be done after all threads finish the current round, so the threads need to be synchronized here. It's definitely doable.

Comment: Possible implementation of parallel k-means: [link](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~wkliao/Kmeans/), [link](https://github.com/ronak197/Parallel-K-means-Clustering/blob/master/k-means_parallel.c)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I’ll see if I’m able to replicate something like that in Python

Comment: any luck with this one? trying the same, sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans fails run out of memory.

Comment: Sorry, no luck so far. I stopped working on it